# Istikhara &marriage

Tags: nikah, istikharah

I prayed istikhara for marriage. Whether i should accept a marriage proposal or wait for someone who i have in mind, attracted to and really like (i don't speak and I'm not in contact with this person). I prayed istikhara for 3 days and on the fourth day a friend of mine told me that the parents of the guy who i like, were considering me for their son. Is that a sign that i should wait for this person?

Answer (score 3):

### Understanding Istikhara

Some people do not well understand hence apply Istikhara, **Istikhara is not used when one is confused and not sure what of two things to choose**, no this is wrong, and if you read the Istikhara Duaa well you will be able to confirm that:

> Oh Allah! If in Your Knowledge this action
>   (which I intend to do) is better for my religion and faith, for my life and end [death],
>   for here [in this world] and the hereafter then make it destined for
>   me and make it easy for me and then add blessings [baraka'] in it, for
>   me….

You see here:

- A person want to do something
- but he or she has no knowledge about if it is good for him/her or not

So he does istikhara then does that specified thing, if it’s good for him Allah will let that thing happen, if it is not, Allah will obstruct  or stop it.

**It is wrong what people think they will get a sign or dream show them the right path.**

So in your case you have two options based on the answer of this question: "*if that person you wish for will never be yours (remove him from evaluation), will you accept the current proposed man?*"

1. If yes, then make istikhara for the current proposal and accept
2. if you do not think the proposed man is good for you, make istikhara
   and reject.

I hope you got the idea now, you need to:

1. decide
2. make istikhara
3. then do what you decided

These are the three steps, then you need to trust Allah will make things happen to the best in your favor.

Answer (score 1):

Salaam alaykum,

Good question. The thing about istikhara is that it's actually a three part process.

1. Preparation: this is where you do your own research. Look into the background of your suitors, understand yourself, etc.
2. Istishara (not a typo): now you ask people of experience and knowledge about your two suitors
3. Istikhara: pray the two rakas and make the dua.

Your answer won't necessarily be in a "sign." It's a natural process, so don't expect anything otherworldly. Your heart will incline one way or another and you should trust that feeling based on you having done the three steps above [(source)](https://www.istikhara.com/)

Comment: Again promotion for your website if you want to copy paste your answers you could link them!